# Call R plots from c++ using RInside/ Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

Is it possible to call the plot functions from the c++ ?
Currently when I try to do that, the ubuntu terminal sort of freezes for sometime ( may be the duration for which the 3d plot would be created and then rotated for a full 360 degrees) and then unfreezes, without ever popping a new window. 
Is this the expected behavior or is there something that I am doing wrong ? How can I get the plots ( R graphics ) to run from within c++ using rinside and rcpp ?

Thnx

-Egon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a working examples in the Rcpp package. Look at the file  `functionCallback/newApiExample.r` in the `examples/` directory.
You may need to experiment with `sleep()` to 'hold' the plot for a moment, or plot to a file and then have the file displayed.  It all depends but you gave little detail.

Comment: I am mostly using the np package, and using npplot function in R. When I do try it, with or without sys.sleep(x.x), it creates a file "Rplots.pdf", but it never opens with any pdf reader.

Comment: Embedding defaults to setting the `interactive` flag to FALSE. I presume you would have to alter that.  Or plot to a png file and have widget display that.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable which deals with the interactive session is `R_INTERACTIVE_DEVICE`.
We need to create a file named `.Renviron` in our home directory, and then add the following code to that file:

`R_INTERACTIVE_DEVICE = X11`  for Linux based systems.

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> ls .Renviron
.Renviron

anisha@linux-y3pi:~> cat .Renviron
R_INTERACTIVE_DEVICE = X11a
```

References:
1. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html
2. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It didn't work for me by default, that's why I spent an hour to search this answer.!

Comment: I would urge to fix the causes of problems, not the symptoms.