# Plotting functions from a C program using R

Tags: c, r, plot

is it possible to plot functions from a C program using R?
Is there a R C API available for plotting? Of course, it is possible to generate a R script from the C code and then call execute this generated script using the system command but I want to call R functions for plotting directly from the C code?

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: I think you might have more luck doing to the other way around and export your C function calculations into R so that R is the driver and your C code provides the values to be plotted.

Comment: Not worth it, IMHO. Export your data from C into a CSV file or similar and import it into R. Or alternatively, just use gnuplot from C.

Answer (score 2):

You might like Rcpp

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

EDIT:
This might be useful as well:
[Call R plots from c++ using RInside/ Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142762/call-r-plots-from-c-using-rinside-rcpp)

Comment: Hmmm, and R has no C API? AFAIK R is developed in C and Fortran. Any links and code samples are welcome ;)

Comment: @Jonas Why do you want to get R to do your plotting? Surely there's easier ways of plotting things. And what's stopping you doing it all in R?

Comment: Jonas, R *does* have a C API which is clearly documented in the *Writing R Extensions* manual.  But what may be a three-liner with Rcpp or RInside can become a ten-or-more-liner with the C API.  Some of us like the abstractions that Rcpp offers---but you are free to ignore them.

Comment: Hi everyone,

first of all: thanks for your replies! What I am looking for is a small C example using R directly without generating a R script and executing it via the system command. In pseudo code I want something like this:

    void plotSinAsPNG()
    {
        /* init R */
        /* create plot */
        /* store plot as PNG image */
        return;
    }

I don't want R to be visible / noticeable to the user. The user should just run the C program and have the plot as output in the form of an PNG image.

I also don't want to use 

Any code snippets

Answer (score 1):

As OneWhoisUnnamed already said, [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) and [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) may be of help if you want to take advantage of C++ rather than C.

Another nice example, completed after the post mentioned in the other answer, is this simple example of embedding R inside a simple Qt application: Qt does the widgets, R does the plotting---see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357765/passing-rinsides-r-instance-as-a-parameter-between-classes-methods) for more, including a screenshot.  This is now in the RInside SVN sources but not yet on CRAN.

Answer (score -1):

You can interface with functions written in C using the .C function.   One example of this is http://madison.byu.edu/bayes/gsnow.txt

The inline package may also be of help.

Comment: Yes, `.C()` is the oldest useable interface, and `.Call()` improves upon it and allows whole R objects to be passed.  That is where Rcpp may be of help.  But plain C is also an option, of course.

Comment: He asks for the opposite: Call R from C. Specifically, to be able to use R as a plotting engine from C.